# How to run a script multiple times

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im using this script to duplicate and rename a template sheet

```
function duplicate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastTabName = ss.getSheets().pop().getSheetName();  // Modified
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp').copyTo(ss);

  // Duplica Template
  sheet.setName(isNaN(lastTabName) ? 1 : Number(lastTabName) + 1);  // Modified
  sheet.getRange("G2").setValue(Number(lastTabName) + 1 );

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);    
}
```

how can i specify in the script, (or better idea to take a number from a cell in my sheet) how many times run it ...

For example, lets say I want to duplicate 10 times my template sheet, then run it 10 times

Any help please ?

Thanks !

Comment: How about a loop?

Comment: im barely new at scripts, is there a way you can tell me more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [JavaScript for Loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp):

---

> The for loop has the following syntax:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

> **Statement 1** is executed (one time) before the execution of the code
>   block.
>
> **Statement 2** defines the condition for executing the code block.
>
> **Statement 3** is executed (every time) after the code block has been
>   executed.

---

Example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  Logger.log(text);
}
```

In your case, put the code you want to repeat 10 times inside the `for` and run it from 0 to 9 times, or 1 to 10, as you prefer (0 to 9 is better as [arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)'s indexes start at 0).